# Find the elements of the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$[0, 1] corresponding to the functional on the same space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to find elements in [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) $W^{1,2}$[0, 1] corresponding to the functional $f(x) =  \int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt$ on the same Sobolev space.

My attempt: $f(x) = (x,y) = \int_{0}^{1}(x(t)y(t) + {x}'(t){y}'(t))dt = \int_{0}^{1}x(t)y(t)dt + \int_{0}^{1}{x}'(t){y}'(t)dt = x(1){y}'(1) - x(0){y}'(0) + \int_{0}^{1}{y}'(t)dt  = x(1){y}'(1) - x(0){y}'(0) - \int_{0}^{1}x(t){y}''(t)dt +  \int_{0}^{1}x(t)(y(t)) - {y}''(t))dt$

Next step, we should solve differential eq according to our functional:
$y(t) - {y}''(t) = 0$
${y}''(t) = 1$
Got stuck in there since I think we need additional condition in our differential eq.

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: you got your integration by parts wrong. you should look for $y$ satisfying $y(0)=y(1)=0$, $-y''+y=1$.

Comment: @daw , oh my bad. But I think we should have ${y}'(0) = {y}'(1) = 0$ instead of $y(0) = y(1) = 0$. Hence, y = 1